# Express middleware: catch error with domain

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to catch errors in a middleware library.
But it doesn't seem to work.
Shouldn't this work?

I'm not getting json back and the server quits.

**server:**

```
var express = require('express');
var mw = require('./lib/middleware.js');

var app = express();
app.use('/mw', mw());
app.listen(3000);
console.log('Express started on port 3000');
```

**middleware:**

```
var domain = require('domain');

module.exports = function(devices) {
    return middleware;        
};

var middleware = function(req, res) {

    var d = domain.create();

    d.add(req);
    d.add(res);

    d.on('error', function(err) {
        res.json(500, { error: err })
        res.end();
    });

    d.run(function() {
        throw new Error('some error');
    });
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22823887/expressjs-and-domain-error-handling-in-middleware/22824448#22824448

Comment: express does try/catch, but why doesn't the domain handle the error first? Than the Try/Catch wouldn't be reached?

Comment: because it is already caught. I start to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a try/catch inside the run function because otherwise the try/catch from express is used.

```
var domain = require('domain');

module.exports = function() {
    return middleware;        
};

var middleware = function(req, res) {

    var d = domain.create();

    d.add(req);
    d.add(res);

    d.on('error', function(err) {
        handleError(res, err);
    });

    d.run(function() {
        try {
            throw new Error('some error');
        }
        catch(err) {
            handleError(res, err);      
        }

    });
}

var handleError = function(res, err) {
    res.json(500, { error: err.message });
    res.end();    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've also struggled with this and found another interesting solution.

Basically You need this kind of middleware:

```
function(req,res,next){
    var d = domain.create();

    d.on('error',next)

    d.run(function(){
        next();
    })
}
```

I've also created npm module, so it can be easily attached to project:

[npmjs - express-async-error](https://www.npmjs.org/package/express-async-error)